# One object in a 2 collections (Reference)

Tags: java, collections, reference

I'm curious about the object reference in java let's say we have a Person object

```
Person object = new Person("Joe");
```

I put it in an `ArrayList<Person>`

```
ArrayList<Person> person_collection = new ArrayList<Person>();
person_collection.add(object);
```

I create a new collection of `Person` again, then copy the items of `person_collection`

```
ArrayList<Person> collection = new ArrayList<Person>(person_collection);
```

If I get the item from `collection`

```
Person p = collection.get(i);
```

Is `p` has a reference to `person_collection`  ??

Comment: Do you mean if p and object both point to the same Person object?

Comment: Yeah... I get it from collection object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, `p` contains in the initialization step at least all the elements of `person_collection`.

So when you directly iterate over this newly created collection, you will get the same pointed `Person` elements that the ones contains into the initial collection.

By the way, as Java never use the pass-by-reference but always the **pass-by-value** method, references themselves are not the same but that does not prevent them to point to the really same objects.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Person "object" variable reference will be returned back in Person "p" variable .

person_collection and collection will be referencing 2 different collections containing the object pointed p.